# Notation Two Headed Arrow

Tags: notation

Does the arrow "$\twoheadrightarrow$" mean surjective?
In other words, for instance, can I gain any additional information from the following statement other than $f$ being surjective:

If $M$ is an $R$-module for some arbitrary ring $R$, $P$ is a free $R$-module of finite type, and $f: M \twoheadrightarrow P$ is a surjective $R$-module homomorphism, then there exists an isomorphism $M \cong P \oplus \mathsf{Ker}(f)$.

Answer (score 5):

It can mean all sort of things, of course. Usually, it means some variation of *surjective* (like *admissible surjection*, or *conflation* or...) In the statement you quote, though, it simply means *surjection*.